# Asking multiple choice questions in Python using an API

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

I’m pretty new to Python. I’m trying to build a multiple choice quiz using Edamam API. It’s currently not flagging any errors but there has to be a neater way to ask the questions, I’m just stuck as some of them require pulling through data from Edamam.

```
import requests


def recipe_search(meal_type, ingredient, Health):
    app_id = "..."
    app_key = "..."
    result = requests.get(
        "https://api.edamam.com/search?q={}&app_id={}&app_key={}".format(ingredient, app_id,

                                                                         app_key)
    )
    data = result.json()
    return data["hits"]


def run():
    meal_type = input("Are you looking for a particular type of meal?: ")
    if meal_type == "yes":
          input("Select an option from the following list:\n - breakfast\n - brunch\n - lunch\n - snack\n - teatime\n > ")
    else: pass

    Health = input("Do you have a dietary requirement?: ")
    if Health == "yes":
        input("Select an option from the following list:\n - vegan\n - vegetarian\n - paleo\n - dairy-free\n - gluten-free\n"
              " - wheat-free\n - fat-free\n - low-sugar\n - egg-free\n - peanut-free\n - tree-nut-free\n - soy-free\n"
              " - fish-free\n - shellfish-free\n >")
    else: pass

    ingredient = input("What ingredient would you like to use?:\n > ")
    results = recipe_search(meal_type, ingredient, Health)
    for result in results:
        recipe = result["recipe"]
        print(recipe["ingredientLines"])
        print(recipe["label"])
        print(recipe["calories"])
        print(recipe["dishType"])
        print(recipe["cuisineType"])
        print()


run()

new_item = input("Add recipe to meal planner?:\n > ")
with open("recipe.txt", "r") as recipe_file:
    recipes = recipe_file.read()

recipes = recipes + new_item + "\n"

with open("recipe.txt", "w+") as recipe_file:
    recipe_file.write(recipes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good beginner project and a good API to practice writing a client.

Add type hints to your function signatures. Python has a weak type system, and the more you can do to strengthen it, the more you'll be able to perform meaningful static analysis and write self-documenting code.

Your program doesn't actually do what you intended. `meal_type` and `Health` aren't sent to the API, and even if they were, they would both be the string `yes`. You need to separate the "yes/no" variable from the "what" variable; the latter you are not assigning at all.

Consider using Edamam's [V2 recipe API](https://developer.edamam.com/edamam-docs-recipe-api).

Pay attention to error values that the API may return, the easiest way being `raise_for_status`.

Delete your `else: pass`. Or, more likely, once you fix your health and meal assignments, the `else` will assign the default value for these variables, probably `None`.

From `new_item` onward, this is fairly puzzling: it might as well be an entirely separate program, as it doesn't use any of the results from your search to store in the file. It would probably a good feature to add: have the user enter the title of their chosen recipe, and store the entire rendered text of the recipe to the file.

Don't read the entire file; just open the file in append mode.

### Suggested

```
from typing import Any

import requests


def recipe_search(meal_type: str, ingredient: str, health_restriction: str) -> list[dict[str, Any]]:
    with requests.get(
        'https://api.edamam.com/api/recipes/v2',
        headers={'Accept': 'application/json'},
        params={
            'app_id': '...',
            'app_key': '...',
            'type': 'any',
            'mealType': meal_type,
            'health': health_restriction,
            'q': ingredient,
        },
    ) as result:
        result.raise_for_status()
        data = result.json()
    return data['hits']


def run_recipe_search() -> None:
    has_meal_type = input('Are you looking for a particular type of meal? ')
    if has_meal_type == 'yes':
          meal_type = input(
              'Select an option from the following list:'
              '\n - breakfast'
              '\n - brunch'
              '\n - lunch'
              '\n - snack'
              '\n - teatime'
              '\n > '
          )
    else:
        meal_type = None

    has_restriction = input('Do you have a dietary requirement? ')
    if has_restriction == 'yes':
        health_restriction = input(
            'Select an option from the following list:'
            '\n - vegan'
            '\n - vegetarian'
            '\n - paleo'
            '\n - dairy-free'
            '\n - gluten-free'
            '\n - wheat-free'
            '\n - fat-free'
            '\n - low-sugar'
            '\n - egg-free'
            '\n - peanut-free'
            '\n - tree-nut-free'
            '\n - soy-free'
            '\n - fish-free'
            '\n - shellfish-free'
            '\n >'
        )
    else:
        health_restriction = None

    ingredient = input('What ingredient would you like to use? ')
    results = recipe_search(meal_type, ingredient, health_restriction)
    for result in results:
        recipe = result['recipe']
        print(recipe['ingredientLines'])
        print(recipe['label'])
        print(recipe['calories'])
        print(recipe['dishType'])
        print(recipe['cuisineType'])
        print()


def add_recipe() -> None:
    new_item = input('What recipe would you like to add to your meal planner? ')
    with open('recipe.txt', 'a') as recipe_file:
        print(new_item, file=recipe_file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_recipe_search()
    add_recipe()
```